# How to write a function that utilizes a length function to recursively find and return a sub-list with the maximum length

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I'm trying to answer this coding question, and I am not having any luck working through this. I cannot figure out how to recursively find the sub-list.

Example: `(max_sub_list '(1 (1 2 3 4) (1 2 3)))` => `(1 2 3 4)`

Here is what my code looks like right now, I need some help.

```
(defun max_sub_list (L)
  (if (>= (my-len (car L)) (my-len (cdr L)))
    (max_sub_list (cdr L))
    (return (my-len (L)))))
```

my-len function:

```
(if L
  (1+ (my-len (cdr L)))
  0)
```

With my original code, I am getting the issue `CDR: 1 is not a list`

I am very new to Lisp, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Update: I decided to use two functions to complete this task. Here's what I got now:

```
(defun compare (a b)
    (cond
    ((> (my-len a) (my-len b))  a)
    (t b))
)
(defun max_sub_list (a)
    (compare(car(a) (max_sub_list(cdr(a)))))
)
```

Update 2: Runs but is not correct.

```
(defun compare (a b)
    (cond
    ((> (my-len a) (my-len b))  a)
    (t b))
)
(defun max_sub_list (a)

)
;;(write (compare '(1 2 3 4 5) '(1 2 3 4)))
(write (max_sub_list '(1 (1 2 3 4) (1 2 3))))
```

The compare method returns the correct value: `(1 2 3 4 5)`
The `max_sub_list` method returns `nil` right now because nothing is inside of it. I need to call the predicate (compare) with the `car` of the list compared to the `max_sub_list` of the `cdr` of the list.

Comment: `1` is an `atom` not a `list` so there is no `cdr`. You need to check whether the current element of the given list is a list at all.

Comment: `(car (a))` cannot be right because `a` is not a function, see Rainer‘s Answer.

Comment: Then how could you compare the first value of the list to the second value of the list inside the max_sub_list??

Comment: I don’t think I understand what you mean. Could you provide all of your code in a version which at least runs without syntax errors?Your code will still fail if the initial list contains atoms, as far as I see.

Comment: See update for code that I have implemented. I also added what I need the function `max_sub_list` to do

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun max_sub_list (L)
  (if (>= (my-len (car L)) (my-len (cdr L)))
    (max_sub_list (cdr L))
    (return (my-len (L)))))
```

There are two problems with the `return` call.

1. Lisp is an expression oriented language. It returns the values of expressions. One needs only to explicitly return a value, when we want to return a value from a part of a computation earlier or from some specific call.
2. `return` does not work here. `return` returns from a block called `NIL`. There is no such block in your code. But there is a block called `max_sub_list` - which is the name of the function, which is also a block one can return from . Thus you can return from that block with: `(return-from max_sub_list (my-len (L)))`. But as I said, in this case you don't need it. The `if` expression returns either the `then` or the `else` value.

The other problem is that `L` is not a function -> it is variable. But your code has `(L)`, which is a function call in Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

For further studies and without any guarantee you could start with this:

```
(defun max-sub-list (list &optional (max-len 0))
  "Returns the length of the longest sublist of LIST."
  (let ((first-element (first list)))
    (cond ((null list) max-len)
          ((atom first-element) (max-sub-list (rest list) max-len))
          (t (when (> (length first-element) max-len)
               (setf max-len (length first-element))
               (max-sub-list (rest list) max-len))))))
```

This returns the maximum length instead of the longest sublist. You should check if you want to use `>` or `>=` when comparing the length of the sublists and if others test cases are needed.

I use `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr` because of my personal style, YMMV.

Comment: Utilizing this code and inserting `car` and `cdr` when needed, I wrote that list above and got NIL, not (1 2 3 4)

Answer (score 0):

tail call recursive solution:

```
(defun max-sub-list (list &optional (acc '()) (max-len 0) (max-list '()))
  (cond ((null list) max-list)
        ((listp (car list)) (if (> (length (car list)) max-len)
                                (max-sub-list (cdr list) acc (length (car list)) (car list))
                                (max-sub-list (cdr list) acc max-len max-list)))
        (t (max-sub-list (cdr list) acc max-len max-list))))
```

or:

```
(defun max-sub-list (list &optional (acc '()) (max-len 0) (max-list '()))
  (cond ((null list) max-list)
        ((and (listp (car list))
              (> (length (car list)) max-len))
         (max-sub-list (cdr list) acc (length (car list)) (car list)))
        (t (max-sub-list (cdr list) acc max-len max-list))))
```